# Why is pseudocode not allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-policy

Re: [C# code to derive tangential points between two circles to create a trapezoid](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11858/pseudocode-to-derive-tangential-points-between-two-circles-to-create-a-trapezoid)

I made the following comment, but since I will probably delete the OP (if I can), I'll post it here:

"With all due respect (and I should have read the rules first), this policy isn't helpful. While I'm capable of posting actual code, it will become very specific (harder to wade through), will not provide a concrete example and would result in wasted effort if my general approach is wrong."

I'm an average programmer trying to make a living. Especially because I work alone I don't have at-work peer review. I'm also trying to be efficient. It would be great before writing code to be able to review the logic. It also might be beneficial to someone who doesn't know C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because Code Review is about ... code.  As a practicing programmer, you should probably also be reading and using [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where "*algorithm and data structure concepts*" is the top item in the list of on-topic areas, and where there is even a "*language-agnostic*" tag.